# Google App Engine asynchronous image upload

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload images to google app engine using asynchronous POST. The problem is I am only able to upload a single image. After that I am getting a out of memory error. I am using angular file upload plug in for upload. My code is as follows

This method I use to create BLOB upload URLS

```
  public @ResponseBody String getBlobstoreUploadUrl() {
       BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
       return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadquestionimage");
  }
```

The method for Blob upload is

```
 public @ResponseBody Map<String, List<BlobKey>> uploadQuestionImage(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    return blobs;
}
```

And my Angular/Javascript code is

```
$scope.fileSelected = function(a,b){
    console.log(a);
    var uploadurl='';
    $http({
        url : '/getImageUploadURL',
        method :'GET',
    }).success(function(url){
        uploadurl = url,
        console.log(url);
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url : uploadurl,
            method: 'POST',
            file: a
        }).success(function(dto){
            console.log(dto);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    })

}
```

I am getting an Error like

```
/_ah/upload/agx0ZXN0YnVkaGFlbnRyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgODyCgw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used angularUpload to emulate the form and used a getter to generate blob url as I require. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like this..

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

<form name="uploadImage" action="<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/UploadImage"
                        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" style="width: 250px" name="image">
```

And in controller you can get blob and url.

For more refer: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html

Comment: You can also refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100573/storing-uploaded-images-on-google-app-engine-with-java

Comment: This is different. This is a synchronus call.. this is not I want.